# Copy a specific worksheet from user selected workbook into the macro workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to achieve below:

1. User selects the workbook
2. The macro should copy the entire worksheet (worksheet name: "Repair Summary by Location")
3. Paste the entire worksheet data into macro workbook by creating a new worksheet named "Last week repair summary"
4. If the user cancels to select the workbook, macro should exit sub.

Preferably, this should be done without opening the selected workbook. But not necessary. If it does open the user selected workbook. it should close it without saving.

Please help.

I got help on a multifile selection and compilation macro in the past that is similar to my requirement, I just tweaked some lines to make it work. I know this is not the right way. Additionally, it does not close if user cancels to select the file.

```
Sub Run()

Dim DataBook As Workbook, OutBook As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetFiles As Variant
Dim MaxNumberFiles As Long, FileIdx As Long, _
    LastDataRow As Long, LastDataCol As Long, _
    HeaderRow As Long, LastOutRow As Long
Dim DataRng As Range, OutRng As Range


'initialize constants
MaxNumberFiles = 1
HeaderRow = 1 'assume headers are always in row 1
LastOutRow = 1

'prompt user to select files
Set TargetFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With TargetFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select the last week report:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
    .Show
End With



'set up the output workbook
Set OutBook = ThisWorkbook 'Worksheets.Add
Set OutSheet = OutBook.Sheets.Add
OutSheet.Name = "Last Week Repair Summary"
Set OutSheet = OutBook.Sheets(1)


'loop through all files
For FileIdx = 1 To TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count

    'open the file and assign the workbook/worksheet
    Set DataBook = Workbooks.Open(TargetFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
    Set DataSheet = DataBook.Sheets("Repair Summary by Location")

    'identify row/column boundaries
    LastDataRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastDataCol = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

'if this is the first go-round, include the header
    Set DataRng = Range(DataSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1),     DataSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))
    Set OutRng = Range(OutSheet.Cells(HeaderRow, 1), OutSheet.Cells(LastDataRow, LastDataCol))


'copy the data to the outbook
DataRng.Copy OutRng

'close the data book without saving
DataBook.Close False



Next FileIdx

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub Run()

Dim DataBook As Workbook, OutBook As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetFile As Variant

'prompt user to select files
Set TargetFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With TargetFile
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select the last week report:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
    .Show
End With

'set up the output workbook
Set OutBook = ThisWorkbook 'Worksheets.Add

If TargetFile.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    'open the file and assign the workbook/worksheet
    Set DataBook = Workbooks.Open(TargetFile.SelectedItems(1))
    Set DataSheet = DataBook.Sheets("Repair Summary by Location")
    OutBook.Sheets("Last week repair summary").UsedRange.Delete 
    DataSheet.UsedRange.Copy OutBook.Sheets("Last week repair summary").Cells(1, 1) 
    'close the data book without saving
    DataBook.Close False

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. Just to bring another variation in it- how to copy entire data on the user selected "Repair Summary by Location" sheet and paste into the sheet "Last week repair summary" WHICH IS ALREADY PRESENT  in the macro workbook (i,e, not adding the sheet)? I tried doing this 
    DataSheet.Copy OutBook.Sheets("Last week repair summary")
But it creates a copy of that worksheet in the macro workbook.

Comment: Updated per your request.

Comment: It opens up the user selected file but does NOT copy data and does NOT paste data in "Last week repair summary" sheet of macro book.

Comment: Check how big your used range is. There may be many blank rows below the last one you expect to see. If you press Ctrl+End, what row does it go to?

Comment: The data range in "Repair Summary by Location" is A1:F32 
This needs to be copied and pasted in "Last week repair summary" sheet of macro book.
The macro creates 5 copies of A1:F32 in last week repair summary sheet and leaves first 40 rows blank

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. That is a very small range, and it is working fine for me. Is there some way you can post your workbooks that I can test them myself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84899/discussion-between-chetan-chimate-and-diegoandresjay).

Comment: Thank you for your help.